# Awarding points to an applicant only once:-no duplicate

Tags: php, mysql

I have my online job shortlisting system where administrators give points to applicants on basis of their competence.I dont want an admin to vote an applicant more than once but he can vote more than once only if it is on a different applicant.how do i go about it?
my code portion is:

```
$values = array();
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    foreach($_POST['name'] AS $key=>$value)
    {
        $name = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['name'][$key]);
        $idNo = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['idNo'][$key]);
        $job = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['job'][$key]);
        $jobTitle = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['jobTitle'][$key]);

        $essential = (int)$_POST['essential'][$key];
        $desirable =(int)$_POST['desirable'][$key];
        $values[] = "('$name','$idNo','$job','$jobTitle',".($essential + $desirable).")";
    }
    if (count($values) > 0)
    {
        if($essential<=5 AND $desirable<=5){
        $insert = "INSERT INTO shortlist(name,idNo,job,jobTitle,points) VALUES ".implode(', ', $values);
        $query = mysqli_query($conn,$insert) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
        if($query)
        {
            header("location:index.php");
        }
    }
    else die("You have violated the rule.Please don't award more than 5 points per category".mysqli_error($conn));
    }
}

$row = "SELECT name,idNo,refNo,department,jobTitle FROM profile WHERE refNo='$getid'";
$query = mysqli_query($conn,$row)  or die(mysqli_error($conn));
$count=mysqli_num_rows($query);
echo $count."&nbsp;applicant(s) for <strong style='color:#669900'>$getid</strong>";
$cnt = 0;


while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query))
{
    $cnt++;
    $name = $row['name'];
    $idNo=$row['idNo'];
    $job = $row['refNo'];
    $jobTitle=$row['jobTitle'];
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>".$row['name']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['refNo']."</td>";
    echo "<td>"."<input type='text' name='essential[$cnt]' class='form-control' width='100%' required>"."</td>";
    echo "<td>"."<input type='text' name='desirable[$cnt]' class='form-control' width='100%' required>"."</td>";
    echo "<input type='hidden' name='name[$cnt]' value='".$name."'>";
    echo "<input type='hidden' name='job[$cnt]' value='".$job."'>";
    echo "<input type='hidden' name='jobTitle[$cnt]' value='".$jobTitle."'>";
    echo "<input type='hidden' name='idNo[$cnt]' value='".$idNo."'>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
echo "<input type='submit' class='btn btn-success' name='submit' value='Submit'>";
"</form>";
echo "</div>";
mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

Comment: different application ??

Comment: If it's different applicant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a database that holds the admin's username and the applicant they voted for. So every time they click the vote button it stores a new record in the database. To prevent them from multiple votes, every time they vote check to see if the records exists by using the `mysqli_num_rows($query)` function. So if the function returns 0, it means they have not voted for the applicant. 
**Here's a general concept of what you need:**

```
$query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM votes WHERE admin='$admin' and applicant='$applicant' ")
$rows = mysqli_num_rows($query);
if($rows == 0){
 //allow vote to happen, not a duplicate
} else {
//duplicate vote

}
```

**SECURITY PROBLEM:** You need to use prepared statements, especially if this a public site.

Also you should invest some time into learning AJAX so that the page does refresh every single time someone votes